# Entity Framework chained where clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to refactor following query so `i.Title.Contains(query) || i.Description.Contains(query)` is there only once while staying within single query (no subqueries) in the resulting sql?

```
if (extendedSearch)
{
    result = result.Where(i => i.Title.Contains(query) || i.Description.Contains(query)
        || (i.CreatedBy.FirstName + " " + i.CreatedBy.LastName).Contains(query)
        || (i.AssignedTo.FirstName + " " + i.AssignedTo.LastName).Contains(query)
    );
}
else
    result = result.Where(i => i.Title.Contains(query) || i.Description.Contains(query));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = result.Where(i => 
    i.Title.Contains(query) || i.Description.Contains(query)
 || (extendedSearch && 
      ((i.CreatedBy.FirstName + " " + i.CreatedBy.LastName).Contains(query)
   ||  (i.AssignedTo.FirstName + " " + i.AssignedTo.LastName).Contains(query))));
```

(keeping fingers crossed that brackets are correct...)

Logical structure in Where expression: **A or (extendedSearch and B)**

If `extendedSearch` is **false** the result depends only on **A**. If `extendedSearch` is **true** the result depends on **(A or B)** - which represents the logic in your query, I hope.

Comment: Oh yes, this is perfectly valid, however I was hoping for solution that would not involve creating one huge `where` clause. Something like when `query.Where(x => x.Foo && x.Bar)` can be also written like `query.Where(x => x.Foo).Where(x => x.Bar)`. This example is simple enough, but with more parameters it gets quite hard to maintain :(

Comment: @Lukáš: I see. Do you know PredicateBuilder? Perhaps it could help for your purpose: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I could not verify this solution for myself right now, but it must be something like that (TI is a type of i in your code sample):

```
Func<TI, Boolean> predicate = i => i.Title.Contains(query) ||i.Description.Contains(query);

if (extendedSearch){
result = result.Where( i=>predicate(i) 
    || (i.CreatedBy.FirstName + " " + i.CreatedBy.LastName).Contains(query)
    || (i.AssignedTo.FirstName + " " + i.AssignedTo.LastName).Contains(query)
); } else result = result.Where(predicate);
```

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This would work in linq to objects, but I need this for linq to entities which works with Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>>. Thanks anyways :)